# For any odd $k>1$, is it true that $k\nmid 2^{2k-1}-1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I didn't get similar results on stack exchange for this.   Every other result speaks of $2^n+1$. I guess that the answer is an 'Yes' to the question in the title. Every way I thought seemed to be closed after certain stage. For instance, I thought
$$2^{2k-1}-1 \equiv 0 \pmod {p},$$
for every prime divisor $p$ of $k$.
This would imply that $2$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$. Hence every prime divisor of $k$ must be either $1$ or $7$ modulo $8$. Hence $k$ itself must be $1$ or $7$ modulo $8$. But, I couldn't go further.

Or is it a conjecture? If this post is a duplicate one (which I couldn't figure out for myself), once I get to know of an answer (or direction), will delete the post.

Comment: It seems really hard to control the non-$k$ divisor of $2^{2k-1} - 1$, and I don't see much relevant information related to pseudoprimes or the like that deal with the $k$ in the exponent as well. Can you clarify if you know the answer? I would imagine someone is going to run a brute force search for you.

Comment: I don't know the answer to it. I guess that the answer is an 'Yes' to the question in the title. I have verified though maxima for all primes till just $10^7$ and I didn't find one.

Comment: What are you actually asking ? Whether there is an odd $k>1$ with $k\mid 2^{2k-1}-1$ ? Or whether there is an odd prime $k$ with this property ?

Comment: Question is as in the title. Is there an odd $k>1$ such that $k| 2^{2k-1}-1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $k$ has only to be odd , there are examples , the solutions upto $10^8$ can be found with this little PARI/GP routine :

```
gp > for(k=3,10^8,if(lift(Mod(2,k)^(2*k-1)-1)==0,print1(k," ")))
80519 107663 1284113 1510313 3933023 4557713 24849833 71871113 80646143 98058097
gp >
```

For an odd prime $k$ however we have $$2^{2k-1}=2^{k-1}\cdot 2^k\equiv 2\mod k$$ hence it cannot have this property.

Comment: Oh thanks! There was an error in my code. I now got it rectified.

Comment: But, is there any explanation for such a strange behaviour? I know that there are lot many such strange situations where we do not find any explanations for the behaviour of numbers.

Comment: Strange in what sense ?

Comment: I mean, I was thinking if it is possible to explain what kind of odds satisfy this. Suppose I hadn't used computer, would it have been possible to arrive at 80519 in any constructive manner by understanding the kind of odds which satisfy $k|2^{2k-1}-1$.

Comment: I have no idea , maybe someone else.